# Spring Junit and annotation based autowiring

Tags: spring, junit, autowired

I added a junit test to a simple spring example but it fails to autowire the json service that I wrote.

What is needed to get autowiring to work in a spring JUnit tests?

To try the failing project out do ...

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/oakstair/spring-boot-cucumber-example
cd spring-boot-cucumber-example
./gradlew test
```

Thanks in advance!

Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("demo")
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

Service interface

```
@Service
public interface JsonUtils {

    <T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> clazz);

    String toJson(Object object);

}
```

Service implementation

```
@Component
public class JsonUtilsJacksonImpl implements JsonUtils {
```

Test

```
    @ContextConfiguration()
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ComponentScan("demo")
    public class JsonUtilsTest {

       @Autowired
        private JsonUtils jsn;
```

Comment: please add the code in question into this question

Comment: Well you can the got in 10 secs by cloning! Its not a lot but a lot to paste here ...

Comment: @GunnarEketrapp nobody gots time to clone your projects....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JsonUtilsTest you can't put a @ComponentScan on the class level here since it isn't a @Configuration class. With a @ContextConfiguration annotation like you are using here it is first looking for a static inner @Configuration class so add one of those with the @ComponentScan and it should work:

```
@ContextConfiguration()
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class JsonUtilsTest {

    @Autowired
    private JsonUtils jsn;


    @Test
    // Note: This test is not tested since I haven't got autowiring to work.
    public void fromJson() throws Exception {
        Integer i = jsn.fromJson("12", Integer.class);
        assertEquals(12, (int) i);
    }

    @Test
    // Note: This test is not tested since I haven't got autowiring to work.
    public void toJson() throws Exception {
        assertEquals("12", jsn.toJson(new Integer(12)));
    }

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan("demo")
    public static class TestConfiguration {
    }

}
```

EDIT: Or you can make Spring boot do the work for you by using the @SpringBootTest annotation with a SpringRunner instead:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class JsonUtilsTest {
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the test class fixed my problems!

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {DemoApplication.class})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add @SpringBootTest

On your test class
And provide your SpringBootApplication class and Json utils class to the classes field of @SpringBootTest

It should look like this

```
@ContextConfiguration()
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes={<package>.DemoApplication.class, <package>.JsonUtil.class } )
@ComponentScan("demo")
public class JsonUtilsTest {
```